# Javascript is not working with any of Telerik's control

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a strange problem, I am working on a Telerik based project for little while now and till yesterday, telerik's controls were able to trigger Javascript functions but since today morning, they just don't trigger. Wondering what could be wrong. I tried everything but no luck. I am calling a javascript function on a row selection of a RadGrid(OnRowSelected), the same function was working till yesterday but today it just does not trigger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nailed it down! :)

Strange but this problem is caused by the auto update of AjaxToolkit Control. Earlier, I was using AjaxToolkit version 7.0607 and yesterday it got updated to 7.0725. Not sure why it is not compatible with Telerik but it was the main cause of my problem. I followed these steps and problem is done away.

1) From NuGet's Package Manager Console, I typed Uninstall-Package AjaxControlToolkit
2) After success confirmation I typed Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit -version 7.0607

This has resolved my problem, hope it helps someone with similar issue.